# Property 'db' does not exist on type 'FastifyInstance<Server

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, fastify

//util file

```js
async function dbconnector(fastify, options) {
  try {
    await client.connect()
    console.log('db connected succesfully')
    fastify.decorate('db', { client })
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
module.exports = fastifyPlugin(dbconnector)
```

//index file

```js
const dbconnector = require('./utils/db')
fastify.register(dbconnector)
```

whenever I try to do fastify.db it shows the below error

Property 'db' does not exist on type 'FastifyInstance<Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse, FastifyLoggerInstance> & PromiseLike

Answer (score 4):

With the way Fastify have set up it's types you need to add the decorators yourself to the `FastifyInstance`. You can do that like so:

```
import { FastifyLoggerInstance, FastifyPluginAsync, RawReplyDefaultExpression, RawRequestDefaultExpression, RawServerBase, RawServerDefault } from 'fastify'

declare module 'fastify' {
  export interface FastifyInstance<
  RawServer extends RawServerBase = RawServerDefault,
  RawRequest extends RawRequestDefaultExpression<RawServer> = RawRequestDefaultExpression<RawServer>,
  RawReply extends RawReplyDefaultExpression<RawServer> = RawReplyDefaultExpression<RawServer>,
  Logger = FastifyLoggerInstance
> {
    db: FastifyPluginAsync;
  }
}
```

You need to tell typescript to pick up this type file if you haven't already set it up in your `tsconfig.json`. An example of doing that would be this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ... your other config
    "typeRoots": [
      "types"
    ]
  },
  // ... the rest of your config
}
```

Then save the configuration in the root of your project under `types/index.d.ts`.

This tells the typescript compiler that you have defined your own types in that file. Extending the `FastifyInstance` to include your decorator should now work.